# Node module.exports

Tags: node.js, module.exports

I want to export my router and some variables from a JS file . how can achieve it .
I have tried :

> **Before:**             `module.exports= router;`
>
> **After:**              `module.exports={router,var1,var2};`// Gives error

please help me out .

How to export router and varables from a js file in nodeJS

Answer (score 1):

You can easily exports controller

```
const getAllUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
   const users = await User.find({})
      res.status(200).json({
          status: true,
          msg: "Get all users successfully",
          users,
    });
} catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

const getUser = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
   const users = await User.find({})
      res.status(200).json({
          status: true,
          msg: "Get all users successfully",
          users,
    });
} catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};


module.exports = { getAllUsers,getUser }
```

export route like

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const adminController = require("../controller/adminController");

router.post("/getAllUsers", adminController.getAllUsers);

module.exports = router;
```